# How to pass a row id to a function in the controller in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have displayed a table using database data.Then I wanted to pass the row id to a function in the controller. How can I do that? Its really great if someone can help me.Thanks inadvance.

I used $rid variable for this. But I got an error.

This is the view

```
foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
    <?php $rid = echo $post->r_id;?>
        <tr id="<?php  echo $post->r_id; ?>" > 
                                            <td style="text-align: center"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/ManageInquiries_controller/viewSummary/?><?php echo $post->r_id');?>"><?php echo $post->Fname; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use . to join String

```
<a href="
<?php echo base_url('index.php/ManageInquiries_controller/viewSummary/' . $post->r_id);?>
">
```